# Why am I getting two dsym files in my ipa?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, dsym

Has anyone seen two dsym files in their ipa? (Note: the two files are pictured below if helpful.) I'm unclear why it's happening and when I symbolicate my crash logs, the line numbers are not at all matching up. I tried symbolicating with each separately and both have different, incorrect line numbers.  I'm using XCode 6.1.1 on Yosemite. Thanks for any info!

[image: 2 dsym files]

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, DSYM can not be found in ipa package. DSYM file can be found by application archive. You should check it in `{archive}/dSYMs/{yourappname}.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/` to find down a file name `yourappname` (not included `.dSYM`) and this is the real dSYM file that you need.

Comment: This is the right answer.  If you're looking for dSyms in your IPA file, you're probably confused (like I was) and actually want to go to Window > Organizer, find the build you submitted, and do a control-click to "Show in Finder".  This archive has your dsyms.

Comment: Can dSYM be rebuilt after a release from checkout of the commit the original build was made from?  I need the dSYM for upload to Google Crahslytics.

Comment: Never mind.  "For Bitcode enabled builds that have been released to the iTunes store or submitted to TestFlight, Apple generates new dSYMs. You’ll need to download the regenerated dSYMs from Xcode and then upload them to Crashlytics so that we can symbolicate crashes.".  See: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#bitcode-download

Answer (score 2):

One for ARMV7 and one for ARM64.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a Today Extension or a Watchkit executable DSYMS?